# Where is Victor Puiseux's grave located?

Tags: 19th-century, mathematics, famous-people

Where is Victor-Alexandre Puiseux buried?

He was a famous French mathematician. According to available information, he died in [Frontenay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frontenay), a very small village France in 1883.

Here are his wiki links for both [English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victor_Puiseux) and [French](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victor_Puiseux).

I tried a multilingual search. I also looked up findagrave.com. No success.

I am not allowed to comment on meta, so here is one instead: Hello. I only have about 10-15 threads to finish. After that I will stop posting these type of questions. Yes, I can post max one per day.
In general I find it difficult to find a grave location. There is the findagrave.com website, which is good but not perfect. Then I can do multilingual search. I have also found national databases of graves for some countries, but they are not good in most cases. A search can be more difficult in case of wrong data on Wikipedia regarding full names and date of birth/death, which happens sometimes.

Comment: Again, this is not a grave discovery site.

Comment: @Jos Please also share your opinions on https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4378/26786 where this general topic is currently discussed…

Comment: I am not allowed to comment there, so here is one instead: Hello. I only have about 10-15 threads to finish. After that I will stop posting these type of questions. Yes, I can post max one per day.
In general I find it difficult to find a grave location. There is the findagrave.com website, which is good but not perfect. Then I can do multilingual search. I have also found national databases of graves for some countries, but they are not good in most cases. A search can be more difficult in case of wrong data on Wikipedia regarding full names and date of birth/death, which happens sometimes.

Comment: I am thankfull for the assistance provided on this discussion forum.

Comment: Thx for being responsive. Just a reminder: [with a reputation of 5 you 'can participate in Meta' and with reputation 50 you can comment everwhere'](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) Others may correct me if 'registered vs unregistered' also plays a role for these privileges…

Comment: Noteworthy that an [official French database](https://www.leonore.archives-nationales.culture.gouv.fr/ui/notice/309593) gives his _place of death_ as known from Wikidata/German Wikipedia. Further hint ["Son acte de décès (no 5) dans le registre des décès de Frontenay pour l'année 1883. L'acte donne les date et lieu de naissance."](https://wikimonde.com/article/Victor_Puiseux)

Comment: @LangLangC: one has to be registered. Thank you for the links you posted. In most cases possible grave, if a grave exists, is indeed a location in the place of death. Sometimes the remains are relocated to a family estate.

Comment: According to [geni.com server entry](https://www.geni.com/people/Victor-Puiseux/2801010) Victor-Alexandre Puiseux has died in Frontenay, Franche-Comté, France. There is a cemetery there. More info I don't have. His body could be cremated or he can have a grave at a different location.

Comment: @Thank you njuffa.

Comment: @njuffa & Jane: As long as this is 'open', and anyone (of you or whoever reads along here) stumbles over an answer, even with limitations, please _do write a proper answer into the box below!_

Comment: @LаngLаngС Don't get me wrong. I have no problem with the question itself, but with the person who asks the same kind of question over and over and over again.

Comment: @Jos That's a position/opinion/nuance I do not share, but respect, fully. And one that's sadly not represented in the meta-discussion.

Comment: I am the same person, I ask the same type of question, but about different famous people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Roland Brasseur, a retired French math teacher, maintains a [website](https://sites.google.com/site/rolandbrasseur/4-les-math%C3%A9maticiens-du-cimeti%C3%A8re-du-montparnasse) "Les mathématiciens du cimetière du Montparnasse" on which he records all the mathematicians buried in the large [Montparnasse Cemetery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montparnasse_Cemetery) in Paris. As of June 2022 he had identified 158 mathematicians there.

Under the update for April 7, 2020, one finds:

> PUISEUX Victor. 1820-1883. ENS. Maître de conférences à l'ENS, astronome à l'observatoire de Paris, professeur à la Sorbonne, Bureau des longitudes.

Clicking on the name leads to a PDF [document](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18MmLRFMPCL3PRlXA8zBRCQVEYvDgfvUy/view) that provides much detailed biographical information about Victor Puiseux. At the top of the document one finds the location of Puiseux's grave within the cemetery: division 14, 2 Sud, 28 Ouest. Towards the end of the document there is a picture of the grave as photographed by the author in 2008.